# Which C function is used to find out if a user exists on the system?

Tags: c, posix

Simple question; what is the function or library that i need to use to write a very simple program (in C) (linux, ubuntu) to find out whether a user exists on the system ?

In bash i'd do :

```
'ls -la /home | grep $user | wc -l'
```

I think it's posix for C (or python) ? Can anyone help me to get started ?

An example would be perfect like :

```
 $ doesUserExist John
 0
```

or

```
 $ doesUserExist John
 1
```

Thanks !

Comment: Oh, and BTW, you only check if the user's home directory is in /home with the above command. You should rather user "getent passwd $user"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getpwnam` is used for all accesses to the passwd database. If it returns NULL, the user doesn't exist.

Comment: ...or the user exists but due to a resource failure the lookup was unable to be performed.

Comment: Also, one should really use `getpwnam_r` rather than `getpwnam` in modern software.

Answer (score 2):

Use: [`struct passwd * getpwnam (const char *name);`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Lookup-User.html#Lookup-User)